# Implementing a Chat backend, what would be the best way to generate and retrieve room ids?

Tags: architecture, chat, uuid, chatroom

I wonder what are the pros and cons of the two approachs I am thinking about.

- 1/ Create room_id by combining users UUID (unique 32 chars) orderered ASCII wise so it would become: `85f14807b0dc470fb42b9df53c55abfb87f14807b0dc470fb42b9df53c55zbfx` where we have a new uuid each 32 chars (here it is a room with 2 users), it would however become increasingly long.
- 2/ create room_id by combining users ID ordered from smallest int to bigger so it would be like:
  `|1|3|7|9|13|` for a room with 5 users having the respective ids, using a special characters to make it as a string.

I think the second approach (using sequential IDs) make more sense as it takes less space into the database than by using the UUID.

Still I think there should be a better way than the two solutions I have envisioned, so I am looking for advice from engineers who have implemented or tinkered with such backend.

Comment: Why would room id consist of users ids at all?  What is the point? What if you have a room with 1k users and you have user ids starting from 1kk? Just generate random uuids for rooms and that's it. If you want some kind of "anonimous rooms" functionality which will be determined by user ids then storing this info in different place to search such rooms would be preferable approach.

Comment: That's precisely because I think there is something wrong with my approach that I look for answers.

Comment: *Don't* do it by concatenation unless it's a room explicitly for 2 users. Otherwise you would have to rename the room when users join or leave. Name rooms as UUID (or any other random-ish value), then keep room membership in a DB table/collection.